# Access to structure parameter from annotation map in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to swift programming and I'm trying to build an application that shows some pin on a map. When the user click on the pin there is an annotation with a button. If the button is clicked it will open an url in Safari.

Following some tutorial I managed to have a functional app with pin and button but I can't manage to open the URL.

This is the code I'm using to build the app:

```
struct WebCam {
  var name: String
  var latitude: CLLocationDegrees
  var longitude: CLLocationDegrees
  var url: String
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let webcams = [WebCam(name: "WH1", latitude: 51.5549, longitude: -0.108436, url: "www.test.it"),
                WebCam(name: "WH2", latitude: 51.4816, longitude: -0.191034, url: "www.google.it")]

func fetchWebcamsOnMap(_ webcams: [WebCam]) {
  for webcam in webcams {
    let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotations.title = webcam.name
    annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: webcam.latitude, longitude: webcam.longitude)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotations)
  }
}

extension FirstViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotations: MKAnnotation) -> 
MKAnnotationView? {
let identifier = "WebCam"
var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView
// 4
if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
  as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
  dequeuedView.annotation = annotations
  view = dequeuedView
} else {
  // 5
  view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotations, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
  view.canShowCallout = true
  view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
    let mapsButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero,
       size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)))
    mapsButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "webcam"), for: UIControl.State())
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = mapsButton
}

return view

}
```

And this is the code to retrieve the UIButton press

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
       if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {

       }
   }
```

I tried to to a simple console print with the URL of the selected webcam by accessing it with

```
let web = view.annotation as! WebCam
let webURL = WebCam.url
```

but it shows an error.

Comment: Attach error String too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebCam` must be a sub**class** of `MKPointAnnotation`

```
class WebCam : MKPointAnnotation {
    var url : String

    init(name : String, latitude : CLLocationDegrees, longitude : CLLocationDegrees, url : String) {
        self.url = url
        super.init()
        self.title = name
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}
```

Then you can create the instances

```
let webcams = [WebCam(name: "WH1", latitude: 51.5549, longitude: -0.108436, url: "www.test.it"),
               WebCam(name: "WH2", latitude: 51.4816, longitude: -0.191034, url: "www.google.it")]
```

`fetchWebcamsOnMap` can be reduced to

```
func fetchWebcamsOnMap(_ webcams: [WebCam]) {
    mapView.addAnnotations(webcams)
}
```

and

```
let web = view.annotation as! WebCam
let webURL = web.url
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

This cast will crash

```
let web = view.annotation as! WebCam
```

You need to subclass the

```
class CusAnn:MKPointAnnotation {
  var url:String?
}
```

And add the annotations like

```
let annotations = CusAnn()
```

Then

```
let web = view.annotation as! CusAnn
let webURL = web.url
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in your code it depict issue is with your Code in below lines

```
let web = view.annotation as! WebCam
```

replace

```
let webURL = WebCam.url
```

with

```
let webURL = web.url
```